# System of Linear Inequalities with 3 variables

Tags: systems-of-equations, linear-programming

I have two systems of inequalities with $3$ variables

The first system of inequality:
$$
\left \{
  \begin{align*}
    ax &> x + y + z \\
    by &> x + y + z \\
    cz &> x + y + z
  \end{align*}
\right.
$$

where $a,b,c,x,y,z>0$

The second system of inequality:
$$
\left \{
  \begin{align*}
    ax + by &> x + y + z \\
    ax + cz &> x + y + z \\
    by + cz &> x + y + z
  \end{align*}
\right.
$$
where $a,b,c,x,y,z > 0$

For both systems, I would like to find the relationship between $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that the system of inequalities has a solution.

For instance, the system of inequalities with $2$ variables below:
$$
ax > x + y \\
bx > x + y \\
a,b,x,y > 0
$$
Can be easily reduced to $ab > a + b$,

that is the equation has a solution whenever $ab > a + b$

I would like to reduce the above system of equalities with $3$ variable $(x, y, z)$ in similar fashion.

I have searched online for system of inequalities with $3$ variables but am not coming up with anything much.

Comment: How have you sped?